# The Shading of Double Petaled Flowers

Tags: functions, quadratics

Here is the shape that I am trying to shade in. I have the outline.

[image]

Here are the equations that I used:

[image]

[image: quad]

I was wondering how I could manipulate these domains and ranges or maybe the equations. I was thinking of maybe using logarithmic functions and exponential functions.

Like this:
[image: op]

However, I don't know how to apply that into here. I was wondering if someone could help me. Thank you

Comment: have you thought of graphing them using polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Here's the Desmos page I used for this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uufjsoibha

[image]